# how to Increase mysql search speed?

Tags: php, mysql, indexing

I have table in MySQL  which has columns
**id(primary key) ,deviceid(varchar) ,date(varchar),time(varchar),value(varchar) parameter(varchar)**
I made mistake by separating time and date fields in my DB columns  and then with my business logic where with lot of repetitive code

A new record is inserted every minute in database every day. My major query is to fetch data between two dates for a given number of deviceids  such that data only one value is selected per interval ( this interval is decide by user input for exampe if interval is 1 hour i need 1 value between interval 00-01 hrs,1 value in terval hrs 01-02 hrs and so on 1 value from 23-24(00) hours )

My query is taking almost a minute to get data for and display for 2-3 days of data . And shorter the interval gets more time it takes .
I am new to databases and only knows basic CRUD operation . I have designed tabled through php myadmin default options.
I read about the concept of indexing to improve search performance and i am confused on which columns should I apply indexing.

Also my `value` columun is currently varchar but values of value column  are all floating numbers(temperature/humidity   of a boiler room). Can changing its type from varchar to int increase my speed ?

here is more explanation

I am using my php to display report
my time is in string format and so is date

for example date is stored as **'08.31.2020'**
and time is stored **'23.05'**  (hours,min)

let say I want data from '08.01.2020' to '08.20.2020' and interval of 1 hour =60 minutes
Here is my business logic  and querys

```
 $time1 ='00.00'
$time2 ='01.00'  // here I have increased time by adding 60 minutes to $time1 .

while(fromDate <= toDate)
{
   for(each device in array)
 {
  $query = "Select parameter,value,time,date from currentdata where deviceid='device[$i]' and date='fromDate' and (time > '$time1' and time <= '$time2' ) order by time limit 1 "

      
}

     $time1=$time2;   //change interval 
     $time2 =$time2 +60 minutes  //     


        If(time1>=time2)
       {
          //  increment From date by 1
       }

 }
```

No of devices are about 30 -35 .
Parameter is just a name  which will be either Temperate of humidity

*Any general advice ,suggestion ,criticism  will be helpful.*

Comment: I always refer to http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql for indexing questions. I haven't looked through it in a while, but reading this through should give you insight into how you may be able to better utilize an index for this query. At a glance, it sounds like you need a multi-column index like `INDEX(deviceid, date, time)`.

Comment: This Question is a dup?  Maybe in another forum?

Comment: I would recommend converting/combining your date/time columns to a standard DATETIME column, because that should increase performance right away. BUT then beware of doing something like `WHERE DATE(datetime) < '2020-09-01'` because when using a function on an indexed column, it doesn't utilize the index. Instead, do something like `WHERE datetime < '2020-09-01 00:00:00'`

Comment: Remember to always store dates and times using a correct data type

Comment: on migration after creating your datetime column,  change your code to insert to this column, then you can use [DATE_FORMAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) to take the string form and `update` the datetime column. Then drop the time and date columns.

Comment: @WOUNDEDStevenJones - And `WHERE datetime < '2020-09-01'` works, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use appropriate datatypes in the table.  Numeric quantities should *not* be put in `VARCHAR`; use `INT`, `DECIMAL`, or `FLOAT`, as needed.  (Or variants on them.)

If your incoming data is not "clean", the read it into a `VARCHAR` and 'cleanse' it as you copy it into the `SMALLINT UNSIGNED`, etc, in the real table.

Also `DATE` must have the year first.

Use things like `+ INTERVAL 1 HOUR` for simple date or time arithmetic.

Usually it is better not to split date and time for storage, but to split *as needed* on output.

On your other Question, I admonished you to do the `SELECT` with a `JOIN`, not a loop.

After addressing all those things, provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`, the new query, etc.  Then I will weigh in on the index.